# python list comperhension, creating list of 100 numbers divided by 7

Tags: python, list, modulo

I'm doing some exercises on Python programming and I stumbled upon a problem, which probably is trivial but still my brain cannot comprehend it.

I'm required to create a list of first 100 number divisable by 7 (so num % 7 == 0) using list comperhension. At first I thought "ehh easy" and wrote

```
list_of_num = [i for i in range(100) if i % 7 ==0]
```

and then it hit me that it's not the thing that the teacher asks me to do (he specifically stated it must be done in list creation without any libraries or methods). How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating many numbers and keeping the good ones, what about generating only the good ones ? Multiply by `7` and you'll get only multiples of `7`

```
list_of_num = [i * 7 for i in range(100)]
print(len(list_of_num), list_of_num ) # 100 [0, 7, 14, ..., 693]
```

or use the `step` parameter of `range` :

```
list_of_num = [i for i in range(0, 7 * 100, 7)]
```

---

If you want to start at `7` and still get a hundred

```
list_of_num = [i * 7 for i in range(1, 101)]
print(len(list_of_num), list_of_num ) # 100 [7, 14, ..., 693, 700]

# or
list_of_num = [i for i in range(7, 7 * 101, 7)]
```

Comment: so simple I knew my brain was thinking in wrong direction! Thanks

Comment: @badbadllama You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Comment: Didn't even know I could do that :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your answer: you are neither using a library (no **import** statement anywhere, nor a method (range is a standard python function).

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is you are only considering numbers that are less than 100.

You should instead create multiple of 7 instead.

```
list_of_num = [7*i for i in range(100)]
```

or

```
list_of_num = [7*i for i in range(1, 101)]
```

if you want to begins from 7 rather than 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
list_of_num = [i for i in range(7, 701, 7)]
```

or you can use:

```
list_of_num = list(range(7, 701, 7))
```

here you are using only the built-in function `range` starting from `7` which is the first number divisible by `7` and go until `700`  with the step `7`, having step 7 will guarantee that each number generated is divisible by 7